does my kafka cluster need expansion and how?
I've run a kafka cluster(3 kafka instances + zookeeper) via docker compose on my server recently(July 2024) with all latest tag for docker images.
I've setup jmx_exporter and node-exporter for monitoring the kafka cluster and the server host, and also the prometheus and grafana.
By July, there're over 1.2K clients (99% are produce, and 1% are consume) connected on in and the application functions now are all fine, but as the clients are keep increasing, I just concern when the server host will reach its limit.
These are the charts I currently have, but actually I'm not quite sure what I can get from them:
node exporter for watch the server host

top from server host

jmx_exporter for watch the inside of kafka instances
overall grafana snapshot



result of vmstat 1 5 in one of docker kafka instance
root@ecs-01796520-002:~# docker exec -it 70314ef51864 bash
[appuser@70314ef51864 ~]$ vmstat 1 5
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
12  0      0 723444 169068 8917012    0    0    60  1535    5    8 50 22 26  2  1
15  0      0 722616 169080 8917808    0    0     4  2760 41451 36304 52 21 24  1  1
 8  0      0 721140 169108 8919176    0    0    84  4480 40002 33518 56 20 23  1  0
12  0      0 719684 169108 8920820    0    0   152     8 40462 35086 56 19 25  0  0
 8  0      0 716452 169140 8921556    0    0     0  4468 40856 35174 55 22 23  1  0

Questions:

how many more clients my server can maintain by given performance charts?
what is the suggested solution to scale for support more clients? like 5K?


This question is similar to: Can you help me with my capacity planning?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

my questions is much more precise, and exactly for kafka cluster related, I don't think it's related to the post you suggested, thx

Can you add to the question the result of command: vmstat 1 5 (executed on one of the kafka instances?

@RomeoNinov I've added a JVM charts from grafana, and also the vmstat 1 5 in post, please help to take a look.

In short: your kafka system is under serious load.

What I see the processors are loaded. See 1st image, CPU load. And from vmstat idle is ~25%. The good point is you do not have blocked processes and just small time of waiting. So from the point of CPU the system is balanced and good loaded.

I see in vmstat good amount of cs and in which mean your software do a lot of system calls/network communication. The value is high but not unseen.

There is not so much disk activity and you have good amount of available memory. So about this you are OK.


From the above point: you system can handle about 150 more clients (but will be on the edge of performance). But to handle 5K clients (producers+subscribers) you need to triple the kafka hosts in clusters. Also as recommendation you should check and balance the brokers. And check if you have (probably yes) replication between topics also to balance it. Of course do not keep two replicas in the same instance.
P.S. about JVM: first optimize and balance on OS level, then step in optimizing JVM.
P.P.S. We can't estimate if this load is normal, it depend on too many parameters.
About my suggestion for triple the cluster, I do not know what is the load (CPU and memory) of the host machine. But if its close to the numbers above you should add at least one physical host.

thanks for the suggestion, and further questions: 1. is it normal for a kafka cluster shows such a high load with only 1.2K clients connected (message rate 3K/s)  2. now 3 instances of kafka are all running in a same machine, you suggest to triple the hosts, what exactly does that mean?

@Shawn, please check my edited answer

the cpu and memory of host is listed in the section of top from server host.
and i see a post say: A old benchmark with 3 nodes was doing 800k messages (~80 mb) per second, with each message being replicated to each other node. from link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51308547/kafka-maximum-number-of-connections

and could you clarify: add a node? does this mean add one more node by updating docker-compose.yml, and re-run it in the same individual host?

@Shawn, I did not said "add a node", I said "add physical machine". And if you want to extend the cluster you need to add physical host, the load of your host is high.

thansk! what is the relationship between the new physical host and the current one? should they're in a same kafka cluster, like 3 nodes in current machine, and another 3 in new machine, and form a new 6 nodes cluster?

@Shawn, IMHO will be better to split the load, make new cluster, but this depend a lot from your load. To discuss this better create new question

thanks, final one, is this serious load normal for case like mine? by given facts: 3K messages/second, 1.2K kafka clients, avg bandwidth for recv/trans 25Mb, Intel Xeon 4 core 3GHz Cpu, 16G memory, all default kafka docker parameters? for me, this load is really not high, how a kafka system can't handle this situation?

@Shawn, your host is loaded ~ 80%. This is indicator for me it is heavy loaded and if you want to add clients, have more messages per second you need to add host(s)

yes, understood your pespective from the system load of 80% which is a clear sign of high load. I just curious, from your experience, is this normal? or anything I may mis-used kafka.

@Shawn, performance depend a lot from the load in to the software itself. W/o schema/design of topics, messages, conversions (if any), replications, etc, we can't tell you more. But as the next step is wise to "play" with java settings like GC, new generations, caching, compression, etc and compare the system load. To discuss this please create new question

opened a new question: https://serverfault.com/questions/1162520/why-is-my-kafka-cluster-under-such-a-high-load-for-only-1-2k-clients-3k-message
