why is my kafka cluster under such a high load for only 1.2K clients, 3K message/s, max bandwidth 25Mb/s
I have a single cloud server, the spec:

Intel Xeon 4 core 3GHz Cpu, 16G memory

I've run a kafka cluster(3 kafka instances + zookeeper) via docker compose on it(docker images were pulled at early 2024) with all latest tag for docker images, one of the kafka node:
kafka0:
    #build: .
    image: "confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest"
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      #DOCKER_API_VERSION: 1.22
      #KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka0
      #KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: LISTENER_PUBLIC://0.0.0.0:9092,LISTENER_INTERNAL_DOCKER://kafka0:29092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_PUBLIC://aaa.bbb.ccc:9092,LISTENER_INTERNAL_DOCKER://kafka0:29092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_PUBLIC:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_INTERNAL_DOCKER:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_INTERNAL_DOCKER
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_OPTS: -javaagent:/usr/share/jmx_exporter/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.19.0.jar=12345:/usr/share/jmx_exporter/kafka-broker.yml
      KAFKA_LOG_MESSAGE_TIMESTAMP_TYPE: LogAppendTime
      #KAFKA_JMX_OPTS: "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=124.222.206.102 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=12345"
      #JMX_PORT: 12345
      KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS: "-Xmx512M -Xms512M"
      #KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "broker_start_test:1:1"
      KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_HOURS: 6
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./my_extensions:/usr/share/jmx_exporter/
    restart: unless-stopped

The monitoring has been all set (jmx_exporter and node-exporter) for the server, and also the prometheus and grafana.
Now there're over 1.2K clients (99% are produce, and 1% are consume) connected on in, thgouh application functions now are all fine, but i see the system is in a heavy load.
These are the charts I currently have:
node exporter for watch the server host


top from server host

jmx_exporter for watch the inside of kafka instances
overall grafana snapshot



result of vmstat 1 5 in one of docker kafka instance
root@ecs-01796520-002:~# docker exec -it 70314ef51864 bash
[appuser@70314ef51864 ~]$ vmstat 1 5
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
12  0      0 723444 169068 8917012    0    0    60  1535    5    8 50 22 26  2  1
15  0      0 722616 169080 8917808    0    0     4  2760 41451 36304 52 21 24  1  1
 8  0      0 721140 169108 8919176    0    0    84  4480 40002 33518 56 20 23  1  0
12  0      0 719684 169108 8920820    0    0   152     8 40462 35086 56 19 25  0  0
 8  0      0 716452 169140 8921556    0    0     0  4468 40856 35174 55 22 23  1  0

Questions:

why under such a small amount of client and data, the cluster behaviors in such high load?
how to scale for support more clients? like 8K?


Don't run 3 brokers on one machine via Compose, use separate ones. Otherwise, mount more disks to distribute IO and increase max heap to prevent memory swapping... The Kafka documentation suggests using 6-8GB max heap

I've added the disk counters, I suppose the disk is not the bottleneck?

@OneCricketeer regarding the 6-8GB max heap, is that really necessary for my situation, could you give a link

Your JVM usage is around 520Mb already, so yes, increase the heap size. The Kafka documentation itself has a section "Running in Production". Regarding disk, if you're running multiple brokers on the same machine, you're needlessly copying the same data multiple times (assuming replication factor higher than one)
